# XCode - Unable to attach Debugger to Action Extension

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-extensions

For my iOS application, I have created an `Action Extension`. When I run this app and the extension, here's what happens:

**Simulator:**

1. Launch App - XCode attaches the debugger
2. Launch Extension - XCode attaches the debugger

**Actual Device:**

1. Launch App - XCode attaches the debugger
2. Launch Extension - XCode is **not able to attach** the debugger

It was working fine few days back, but now it's showing this behavior. Also, I am using the same device, that I used before.
Before, every time when I connected the device to my Mac, I used to get an alert for confirmation on the device, but now I don't even get that. Though, I can still see the device in XCode.

My configuration:
XCode: 7.3.1 
OS: OSX El Capitan (Version 10.11.4)

Is there anything that can be done? Also I am not able to find how to unpair the device from XCode/Mac and pair it again so that I could get the confirmation screen again.

Comment: I think this a bug in xcode i had the same issue it sometimes worked and sometimes doesn't and xcode freezes.

Comment: Check the device console (it's accessed by the little disclosure widget in the LLHS of the content pane in the Devices window, after you've selected your device.)  Look for "debugserver" in the log, that's the process that manages debugging processes.  See if debugserver gets run at all on your Action Extension.  If not, then there's some problem higher up in Xcode.  If you do see log messages from debugserver, look for suggestive errors either from debugserver or system components around the same time.  It might be good to file a bug about this as well (http://bugreporter.apple.com.)

Comment: Thanks @JimIngham, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

This was completely screwed up in xcode 8.1

I've filed 29064806 with Apple.

The only recorse is to fallback to a version of xcode that works.

In my case that's 8.0 (where you get this not nearly as frequently)

disabling System Integrity Protection does not help. It's a bug in xcode
(lldb or whatever)